# Are there any settings I can tweak to speed up blender?

Tags: customization, performance

I'm running blender on an older computer and it is a bit sluggish. Are there any settings I can change to get better performance out of the UI?

I'm using blender 2.8

Comment: Hello :). You can decrease viewport resolution in *Render Tab > Performance> Viewport*. That should help.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding this option. I should not that I'm using blender 2.8.

Comment: This answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/106217/56368 helps